# Powershell select the most recurring values

Tags: powershell

I have this values after my scrip:

### Username

user1
user1
user1
user1
user1
user1
user1
user1
user1
user2
user2
user2
user2

i want to select the most recurring user, how can i do this?

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i use insert code botton....excuse me!
Where is the botton for powershell code?

Comment: [There is no button for PowerShell code; there is a generic button to format as code](http://imgur.com/a/bKJx8). You will still have to actually put the code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having some code, or some exemple to work on would have been easier. 
But let's say you have all your values stored in a variable

```
$values =  "user1", "user1", "user1", "user1", "user1", "user2", "user2", "user1"
```

if you want to get the most recurring one. 
You can do something like this

```
$values | group | sort Count -Descending | select name -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name
```

The output would be "user1"

Hope it will help. And if it doesn't, then please provide more detail and information on what you want to do.

Have a good day